# Error pushing images to docker registry inside kubernetes and ingress

Tags: kubernetes, docker-registry

I'm working on docker for desktop kubernertes installation and i want to deploy a docker registry behind ingress.
I already deployed a registry and if I access to the catalog api using ingress it works. 
But when i try to do a push i have this error:

```
error parsing HTTP 404 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value: "<html>\r\n<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx/1.15.11</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
```

This is the yaml I used fo the creation of volume, deployment and service

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: dev-registry-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/host_mnt/c/docker-registry/dev-registry"
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: dev-registry-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dev-registry
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dev-registry
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: dev-registry
          image: registry:2
          ports:
            - name: http-port
              containerPort: 5000
          volumeMounts:
            - name: docker-data
              mountPath: /var/lib/registry
      volumes:
        - name: docker-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: dev-registry-pv-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: dev-registry
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000   
  selector:
    app: dev-registry
```

and this is the ingress rule i have created

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: sudoku-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "600"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: dev-registry.sudoku.test.it
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: dev-registry
              servicePort: 5000
            path: /
```

where dev-registry.sudoku.test.it point to the cluster ip of kubernetes.
I already add the address in the insecure list of docker and if I make a get request to the url http://dev-registry.sudoku.test.it/v2/_catalog it responds correctly.

I also tried to expose the registry as a NodePort and in this case the push works correctl, so the problem is the ingress configuration.
How have i to configure ingress?

I also try this https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/docker-registry but changing only the registry address it doesn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The container daemon is running outside of kubernetes. Therefore it can not use the kubernetes service to access the registry.
You can either use a NodePort, as you did, or you can use a regular, externally resolveable hostname that points to your ingress.
(Of course you could add a host entry to the hosts.txt file as well, but I discourage that since it can cause hard to diagnose problems, if someone is not aware of that configuration.)

Another option is to use an external docker registry of course.

Comment: this is what i did. I add a hostname in my host file pointing to the ingress controller. but this is the problem I have. I forget to say i have installed MetalLB, so my ingress is of type LoadBalancer

Comment: Your service is of type ClusterIP in the question. You can additionally expose a service through ingress, but there is no such thing as ingress with type LoadBalancer. Do you have the DNS entry for dev-registry.sudoku.test.it AND tag your docker image accordingly? (not something like 'dev-registry' or 'dev-registry:5000' )

Comment: In ingress, as you can view up, i have a rule that point to dev-registry.sudoku.test.it. In my host file i have this entry "192.168.1.2 dev-registry.sudoku.test.it". 
I think the rule is correct because if i point to http://dev-registry.sudoku.test.it/v2/_catalog it works and respond.

For creating the image and tagging i'm using a maven plugin configured as follow
<repository>dev-registry.sudoku.test.it/${project.artifactId}</repository>

The response i have is from nginx that cannot talk to the pod i think

Comment: I wonder if you might have multiple nginx running - the answer you get is '404 not found', I would expect a 502 bad gateway, if nginx is correctly performing the ingress duties but can not talk to the pod. So either you talk to a different nginx or you have a mismatch in the configuration. Can you manually push an image from your machine where you execute the test request to the _catalog resource?

Comment: The only nginx i have is the one on kube. I tried to push from my machine and i have the same error. 
Executing the docker images command i found this as a tag: dev-registry.sudoku.test.it/sudoku
could it be this the problem? i was wondering if on nginx it searches for the sudoku path that it doesn't exists in the ingress rule

Comment: are you using docker for mac or docker for windows, or is it just a linux machine? are you sure that you can access the url with curl on your machine using https? how did you configure TLS for the ingress?

Comment: i'm using docker for windows and kubernetes is the one provided with it. I already set the docker registry url in the insecure registry list. At the moment i have no tls fo ingress configured

Comment: Where did you add the host entry then? on your windows host or the docker/kubernetes vm? The whole setup sounds fragile to me, consider using a real DNS host name and TLS certs. You could manually or automatically obtain them using let's encrypt, for example.

Comment: I add the address to the windows host. It's only a test on my machine so i don't need to make it robust. I know i'd have to use a tls certificates but at the moment i don't want to do it. Probably a second step will be this. I'm doing it "for study"